# javap difference when compiling with/without assertion

Tags: scala, javap

*Scala for the Impatient* Chapter 15 Exercise 10: Add `assert(n >= 0` to a `factorial` method. Compile with assertions enabled and verify that `factorial(-1)` throws an exception. Compile without assertions. What happens? Use `javap` to check what happened to the assertion call.

My code:

```
object Test {
  def factorial(x: Int): Int = {
    assert(x >= 0, "Call to factorial must be >= 0!")
    x match {
      case 0 => 1
      case x: Int => x * factorial(x - 1)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    factorial(-1)
  }
}
```

I compiled with `scalac` first, inspected it using `javap Test`, then compiled again with `scalac -Xelide-below MAXIMUM` and inspected with the same command - I can't seem to find a difference between the two.

I understand compiling with assertions will throw the exception when I try to execute the program, and compiling without assertions will cause a stack overflow error, but I can't find the difference in `javap`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I try this with `javap -v` I find the following lines in the version with assertions enabled, but not in the other:

```
   20:  invokevirtual   #27; //Method scala/Predef$.assert:(ZLscala/Function0;)V
   ...
   27:  if_icmpne       34
   30:  iconst_1
   31:  goto    55
```

So that certainly looks okay.

The problem may be that you're either not looking at the bytecode (which requires the `-c` or `-v` flag to `javap`), or—much more likely—that you're looking at the output of `javap` for the `Test` class, not `Test$`. See for example *[Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combining-scala-and-java.html)* for more detail:

> For every Scala singleton object, the compiler will create a Java
>   class for the object with a dollar sign added to the end. For a
>   singleton object named `App`, the compiler produces a Java class named
>   `App$`. This class has all the methods and fields of the Scala
>   singleton object.

If you list the contents of the directory you've compiled in, you'll see both `Test.class` and `Test$.class`. Using `javap -v Test$` will show you the latter, which is where you'll find the difference.